# Pipeline release error - AttributeError: 'VirtualMachine' object has no attribute 'time_created'

Tags: python, pipeline, ado

I am not sure how to resolve this error when it is occurring in my Pipeline release:
[image]

It's related to the VM creation date in my script:

```
def list_debugvms():
    debug_vms = compute_client.virtual_machines.list(resource_group_name)
    ticket_number_list = [ ]
    for vm in debug_vms:
        if vm.name == "bug-devops-vm-0":
            continue
        json_string = vm.tags
        ownerEmail = json_string['OwnerEmail']
        ticket_number = vm.name.split("-")[1]
        date = datetime.datetime.strftime(vm.time_created, "%d-%m-%Y")
        print("virtual machine name:", vm.name , ", ticket number:" , ticket_number , ", Owner Email:" , ownerEmail , ", creation date:" , date)
```

If I run this python script locally, it works just fine. But in my ADO Pipeline I am getting the error above.
Any ideas on how I resolve this?